# different from Foo.class.barMethod() and Foo.barMethod()

Tags: java

I saw this statement:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/foo.fxml"));
```

what is the different between:

```
Foo.class.barMethod() and Foo.barMethod()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo.class` returns an instance of `Class<Foo>` class, so `Foo.class.barMethod()` is only valid if `barMethod` is an instance method in the `Class` class (or its `Object` super-class). `Foo.barMethod()` calls a static method of the `Foo` class.

It's not likely that both would pass compilation for a given `Foo` class and a given `barMethod` method, unless you declare in the `Foo` class static methods having the same signature as instance methods of `Class` or `Object` classes (which probably wouldn't make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

There's no relationship whatsoever between the two idioms.

The first: `Foo.class.barMethod()` will invoke a method of the class `Class`, namely on a `Class<Foo>`.

It's used for reflection.

Therefore, `Foo.class` won't scope to `Foo`'s static (or instance) methods.

The second is simply a `static` invocation of `barMethod` on `Foo`.